# Is it bad practice for a class to register an event handler for another class?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

Should the event subscriber always register the event handler, or is it ok for another class to do it?

Example:

```
class EventPublisher {

    public event EventHandler Event;
}

class EventSubscriber {

    public void Handler(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
}

class Glue {

    private EventPublisher _publisher = new EventPublisher();

    private EventSubscriber _subscriber = new EventSubscriber();


    public Glue() {
        _publisher.Event += _subscriber.Handler;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Glue` seems to take a role somewhat similar to a [`Dispatcher`](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher) in Flux architecture semantics.

Comment: Make sure if it is required to create new instance of `Publisher` every  in `glue` or not (assuming glue will be called every time for new instance of subscriber) , as currently you are creating a pair of `Pub-Sub` , event will work within this pair only. It will not work if you want one publisher and multiple subscribers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should the event subscriber always register the event handler, or is
>   it ok for another class to do it?

There is nothing inherently wrong with this design per se, though it really depends on your architecture and how scaleable and decoupled you want it.

*Just a note, there is no context with the generic hypothetical you have put forward with `Glue` so its hard to tell your exact requirements.*

...

These days, i rarely write traditional events and tend to use a more modern approach of Pub/Sub Producer/Consumer *Decoupled Messages* or an [Event Aggregator](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) (depending on the frameworks you are using). Consumers can subscriber at will, and producers can publish at will without any prior knowledge of each other. Martin Follower goes into this pattern in more detail on his site.

More-so, the advantages with Decoupled Messages (and kin), is consumers can subscribe to a conversation without having any previous knowledge of who the producers are, which gives you better [decoupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) which in turn creates a more maintainable and scalable system. If the system becomes large enough, pushing classes to [Microservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices) can be a lot less painful.

On saying that, if this is only a very simple implementation (and tightly coupled implementation) there is nothing wrong with standard vanilla ice-cream flavored .NET events and having your subscriber register the event handler, though once again you have to break this down into the most logical concern for your design.

I.e should a SoundManager inherently know about a dog and its bark. Or should your dog class register to the sound manager. Your design intuition should lead the way

Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatic, it is not wrong and will work smooth for you.

In fact you need to do this in the case where in `EventSubscriber` of which method 
 (`Handler`)should be called on `Event` , doesn't have object of `EventPublisher` class.

How to subscribe events is subjective matter, it depends on your over all flow and comfort.

**But According to me, subscribing event in side of subscriber class make code more readable and easy to understand**

you see to subscribe an event of any class, subscriber class must have an object of that class, but here in your example it doesn't have.

Generally people design architecture in such method when subscriber class itself hold the object of publisher class. This design has its own benefits in some flow, see below example,

```
public class EventPublisher
{
    public event EventHandler HeavyLogicDone;

    public void ExposedMethod(string subScriberSpecificData)
    {
        Thread logicCaller = new Thread(() => HeavyLogic(subScriberSpecificData));
        logicCaller.Start();
    }

    private void HeavyLogic(string subScriberSpecificData)
    {
        //logic which may take time
        if (HeavyLogicDone != null)
            HeavyLogicDone(this, new EventArgsClass(subScriberSpecificData));
    }
}
```

here `EventPublisher` class has a publicly exposed functionality, which should be called by `EventSubscriber` , but as this method may take time, it is being written in thread.

Now problem, as it is in thread, call of this method will return soon after starting the thread, subscriber can not start its functionality which is dependent on this method's result, it must wait. So to notify subscriber that task has been done, there is an event.

```
public class EventSubscriber
{
    string currentData = "";
    public EventSubscriber(EventPublisher eventPublisher, string data)
    {
        currentData = data;
        eventPublisher.HeavyLogicDone += eventPublisher_HeavyLogicDone;
        eventPublisher.ExposedMethod(currentData);
        //Contineous without waiting for heavy logic to compelete
    }

    void eventPublisher_HeavyLogicDone(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(((EventArgsData)e).subScriberSpecificData == currentData)
        {
           //Do further task which is dependant to result of logic
           //if now subscriber doesn't need to listen this event anymore
           ((EventPublisher)sender).HeavyLogicDone -= eventPublisher_HeavyLogicDone;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can seen when to subscribe an event and when to unsubscribe it, subscriber has all control now.

---

But, if you would be doing like this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    EventSubscriber subscriber1 = new EventSubscriber("sub1");
    EventSubscriber subscriber2 = new EventSubscriber("sub2");
    EventPublisher pub = new EventPublisher();
    pub.HeavyLogicDone += subscriber1.eventPublisher_HeavyLogicDone;
    pub.HeavyLogicDone += subscriber2.eventPublisher_HeavyLogicDone;
    pub.ExposedMethod("sub1");
    pub.ExposedMethod("sub2");
}
```

First problem : As you can see, every time you are creating an instance of Subscriber, you have to explicitly write it's subscription and calling of publisher's method for current subscriber. that is coupled code, and you need to keep doing this every time.

and subscriber class

```
public class EventSubscriber
{
    string currentData = "";
    public EventSubscriber(string data)
    {
        currentData = data;
    }
    public void eventPublisher_HeavyLogicDone(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(((EventArgsData)e).subScriberSpecificData == currentData)
        {
           //Do further task which is dependant to result of logic

           //if now subscriber doesn't need to listen this event anymore
           ((EventPublisher)sender).HeavyLogicDone -= eventPublisher_HeavyLogicDone;
        }
    }
}
```

Second problem : as subscription is not in control of subscriber class, and unsubscribing can be done only withing subscriber class. Code will be little mess to understand.